# React code-splitting eror. Page is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I have used code-splitting using React lazy. No errors are showed, but the page is not displayed. The following code is inside the index.js
What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {Suspence,lazy} from 'react';


// Imported Pages
const HomePage = lazy(() => import("./components/home_page/index"));
const MoviePage = lazy(() => import("./components/movie_page/index"));

const App = () =>(
  <Router>
    <Suspence falback ={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/movie_page" component={MoviePage}/>
    </Switch>
    </Suspence>
  </Router>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();

export default App
```

Comment: Have you called the dom render?

Comment: No I havent. @Van

Comment: perhaps that's why the page is not rendered? Import `ReactDOM` and call the render method, i.e.  `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`. Also change your `App` stateless component to only return the jsx (`<Router> ... </Router>`) without returning the root element